# jQuery Mobile Listview Swipe Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a standard JQM page with a ListView with auto generated dividers.

I'd like to be able to add some functionality that would allow the user to swipe left OR right on an item within the listview and it done either of the following;

1. Reveal a star icon and create some info in localstorage. On swiping a second time change the icon to a 'hollow' star and remove the value in localstorage
2. Reveal a 'hollow' star icon which when clicked on creates a value in locastorage and the icon is replaced with a 'filled' star. Likewise, if the star is pressed a second time, the localstorage value is removed and the icon reverts to a 'hollow' star

I'm sure I've seen info on a similar topic elsewhere but can't seem to find it today. Where can I start?

Comment: Something similar to this? http://codepen.io/Palestinian/details/xBDHi/

Comment: Yes, but I've just added the css and js from your codepen and its not working for me. I cant get the sliding action to work, and no errors are showing in the FireBug console. I can't see why, although im hopefully just missing something really simple.

Comment: is your listview `inset` or not?

Comment: Im using Brackets editor by Adobe, and it adds in its own hooks to enable a live preview mode. Let me just compile the app and see if it works when run without Brackets.

Comment: The demo isn't 100% functional, it was only an experiment. I'm working on it now.

Comment: Agh! Sorry the list view I'm trying to use this on ISN'T inset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65708/discussion-between-omar-and-phill-healey).

Comment: This posts has had over 1,000 views yet not a single upvote and only 1 star! ;-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `span` element which will contain *star*. Add spans before each `li` element.

```html
<ul data-role="listview" id="list">
  <span class="yellowStar"></span>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <span class="hollowStar"></span>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <span class="hollowStar"></span>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <span class="hollowStar"></span>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <span class="hollowStar"></span>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Apply the following CSS for both *filled* and *hollow* stars.

```css
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static {
  overflow: initial; /* to hide spans underneath */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease; /* transition effect */
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 300ms ease;
          transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

ul span {
  float: right;
  padding: 1.3em 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

ul .yellowStar {
  background-image: url(filled.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

ul .hollowStar {
  background-image: url(hollow.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And then attach `swipeleft` to reveal star.

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul span", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("yellowStar hollowStar");
}).on("swipeleft", "ul li", function (e) {
    $(this).off("click");
    $(this).css({
        transform: "translateX(-40px)"
    }).one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function () {
        $(this).one("click swiperight", function () {
            $(this).css({
                transform: "translateX(0)"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Whenever `swipe` is fired, it also fires `click`, hence, `.off("click")` is essential when `swipe` triggers. However, once the transition ends, `click` and `swiperight` listeners are attached to close/hide star.

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/P7IaUgBPOWDkFI3IYt0Y?p=preview)**

Comment: Ive got a few issues with this at present: 1) My stars are visible, but only clickable once Ive swiped left to officially reveal them. They obviously need to be hidden to start with. 2) Its necessary to remove focus from a 'li' before it will allow me to open any other listitem via a swipe. So for example I either need to click one of the revealed stars, scroll the page or right click anywhere then press escape to cancel the mouse menu. 3) My listview items use a onclick event, as they link to other pages. This seems to be preventing me from 'unrevealing' the stars, although it's not important

Comment: @PhillHealey in which browser have test it? Are list items clickable or read-only like in my demo? I didn't get #2.

Comment: All content in li is wrapped in an 'a' tag with an empty href value and an 'onclick=' attribute which calls a function that $.mobile.changePage to load the next page.

Comment: Ok I'll check the code. Come to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65708/discussion-between-omar-and-phill-healey